# Mongoose.js: get mongo db name/url from model instance

Tags: mongoose

I create mongoose.js model:

```
db = mongoose.createConnection(mongoUrl)

model = db.model('Model', schema)
```

can I get mongoUrl (or server and DB name) from model?

Comment: `db.name`,  `mongoose.connection.name`, or `mongoose.connections[0].name` also work

Comment: Confirming this works ^, see: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-name

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, you can reference the original DB connection through `model.db`. So you can get all the connection information you need like this:

```
console.log(model.db.host); // localhost
console.log(model.db.port); // 27017
console.log(model.db.name); // myDatabase
```

Comment: cool, that worked for me. Is there a way to get the connection url information, without pointing to a specific model, but getting it from require(''mongoose") somehow?

Comment: @AlexanderMills, I know this is a bit late, but yes, `mongoose.connection` will be the same as `model.db` as long as your model is using the default connection, which it most probably is.